# Python warning message output

Tags: python, python-3.x

With this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import warnings

if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
    ...
else:
    warnings.warn("Python 3.x is required!", RuntimeWarning)
```

And the else output I get is:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\..., line 10
    warnings.warn("Python 3.x is required!", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Python 3.x is required!
```

Is there any way of getting rid of the first 3 lines of the output and only display "RuntimeWarning: Python 3.x is required!" ?

Comment: If you only want the last line to be outputed, why not print it?

Comment: have you tried `warnings.showwarning = send_warnings_to_log`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

from https://pymotw.com/2/warnings/#stack-level-in-warnings

> Stack Level in Warnings
>
> You’ll notice that by default the warning message includes the source
>   line that generated it, when available. It’s not all that useful to
>   see the line of code with the actual warning message, though. Instead,
>   you can tell warn() how far up the stack it has to go to find the line
>   the called the function containing the warning. That way users of a
>   deprecated function see where the function is called, instead of the
>   implementation of the function.

```
# warnings_warn_stacklevel.py
import warnings

def old_function():
    warnings.warn(
        'old_function() is deprecated, use new_function() instead', 
        stacklevel=2)

def caller_of_old_function():
    old_function()

caller_of_old_function()
```

Notice that in this example warn() needs to go up the stack 2 levels, one for itself and one for old_function().

```
$ python warnings_warn_stacklevel.py

warnings_warn_stacklevel.py:18: UserWarning: old_function() is deprecated, use new_function() instead   old_function()
```

Comment: Why when I am setting stacklevel=2 I am getting this error? 'File "C:\Users\...\Python\Python35\lib\idlelib\run.py", line 351                     exec(code, self.locals)'